# How to upload a dataset folder to an already existing folder in vs code (connected to remote ssh)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I kind of have a structure of my vs repository as follow:

```
* shh remote host 
    * workspace 
        * main folder
           * folder where I want to upload a 20 GB file of dataset
```

Please note that I can't locate the folder in the computer system. How can I upload a zip file or a direct folder in the 'folder where I want to upload a 20 GB file of dataset'

I tried push command and also tried to copy paste the stuff there.

Comment: don't use VSC, use the terminal and `scp` to copy files to remote computers

Comment: I don't have access to terminal or scp as my organization manages it and for any small project I don't find comfortable to approach admin

Comment: how do you get a (small) file on the remote machine? This is basic stuff so ask your admin how to do it, or write a simple server on the remote side in python that listens to a socket and dumps everything it receives to a file, and on the local side dump a file to the remote socket, you can add an end-of-file message, that does not get stored in the remote file

Answer (score 0):

The comments have given a reasonable solution. Of course, if you must use SSH, you can use [rsync](https://rsync.samba.org/) to transfer files.

An alternative to [using SSHFS to access remote files](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_using-sshfs-to-access-files-on-your-remote-host) is to use rsync to copy the entire contents of a folder on remote host to your local machine. The rsync command will determine which files need to be updated each time it is run, which is far more efficient and convenient than using something like scp or sftp.

YOU can read [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_using-rsync-to-maintain-a-local-copy-of-your-source-code) for more details.